# Python how to concatenate string to bytes with \x

Tags: python, string, encryption, byte

I'm trying to add a string message to bytes that represent a signed digest of the message for tcp transmission. The client has the signed digest as bytes and the message as a string.

`` digest = b'd-\xfc*\x7f\xfc\xabr6S>\xa5\xe5\xff\xdd\x80o\xf2\x93\xa0\xdeR\x7f\x1e%W\x81Z\xf2\x06\x12(\x1c\xad"\x1a\x8aNFE\x8ba\x82\xfc\xe19\xe2\x80\x87\xa7\xcf\xbe\x88\xd3\x11}4\r\xc3\x94E\x11#\xbc\x8cF\xd4D+\xdb@e\xb5\x0cVC\x12\x04|J\x9ey\xb8\x88[@\x00ib\xae\x12\xb0\xca\x14X@\rl\xdf\x97\xf4rra\xf1\xa4\xc1\x07\xe2r\xf4\x8f]\xcb\x02\x95\x90z\xc8\x9d\xa6\xa7\x0b^\xc3t\xb8\x01\x89N\xa3\t,\x1c\x06ki\xdb\xdb\x9a6\xbd\xb3W\xfdQ\xeai1\xe2z\xe1Td\xd0\xa0\xc7N\xe4W\x8f\xa0\x8fz`6\x12<\xe9\xdd\xe6:\xfci\xae\x0e\xc3\xfeQ\xaa\xefFw{\x84Ly]\xfc\xe0\xf3G\xa8\xfeA\x9d\xb5+s\xc1\xdf\x98\xb7\xdb.tp+\xd1\xbe\xe1\x15\xba\xa3\xfb\xee\xcf\xf4\x1d\xec\x853Y\xc2\xec\x1cf\x1a5%\xb2!o\x88\x83\x14\x1d"2\xaa\xdc\x03\x97\xd2\xc7\xba\xe8\xe9\x81\xb9\xd0%\xdf\x98b\xf0' ``

`message = hello"`

If I use message.encode() message is converted to bytes but it is `b'hello'` without the \x.

If I concatenate with `digest + message` the client now has this: `` md: b'd-\xfc*\x7f\xfc\xabr6S>\xa5\xe5\xff\xdd\x80o\xf2\x93\xa0\xdeR\x7f\x1e%W\x81Z\xf2\x06\x12(\x1c\xad"\x1a\x8aNFE\x8ba\x82\xfc\xe19\xe2\x80\x87\xa7\xcf\xbe\x88\xd3\x11}4\r\xc3\x94E\x11#\xbc\x8cF\xd4D+\xdb@e\xb5\x0cVC\x12\x04|J\x9ey\xb8\x88[@\x00ib\xae\x12\xb0\xca\x14X@\rl\xdf\x97\xf4rra\xf1\xa4\xc1\x07\xe2r\xf4\x8f]\xcb\x02\x95\x90z\xc8\x9d\xa6\xa7\x0b^\xc3t\xb8\x01\x89N\xa3\t,\x1c\x06ki\xdb\xdb\x9a6\xbd\xb3W\xfdQ\xeai1\xe2z\xe1Td\xd0\xa0\xc7N\xe4W\x8f\xa0\x8fz`6\x12<\xe9\xdd\xe6:\xfci\xae\x0e\xc3\xfeQ\xaa\xefFw{\x84Ly]\xfc\xe0\xf3G\xa8\xfeA\x9d\xb5+s\xc1\xdf\x98\xb7\xdb.tp+\xd1\xbe\xe1\x15\xba\xa3\xfb\xee\xcf\xf4\x1d\xec\x853Y\xc2\xec\x1cf\x1a5%\xb2!o\x88\x83\x14\x1d"2\xaa\xdc\x03\x97\xd2\xc7\xba\xe8\xe9\x81\xb9\xd0%\xdf\x98b\xf0hello' ``

But after being transmitted and unencrypted the encoded string message is no longer present. The server receives only: `` md:  b'd-\xfc*\x7f\xfc\xabr6S>\xa5\xe5\xff\xdd\x80o\xf2\x93\xa0\xdeR\x7f\x1e%W\x81Z\xf2\x06\x12(\x1c\xad"\x1a\x8aNFE\x8ba\x82\xfc\xe19\xe2\x80\x87\xa7\xcf\xbe\x88\xd3\x11}4\r\xc3\x94E\x11#\xbc\x8cF\xd4D+\xdb@e\xb5\x0cVC\x12\x04|J\x9ey\xb8\x88[@\x00ib\xae\x12\xb0\xca\x14X@\rl\xdf\x97\xf4rra\xf1\xa4\xc1\x07\xe2r\xf4\x8f]\xcb\x02\x95\x90z\xc8\x9d\xa6\xa7\x0b^\xc3t\xb8\x01\x89N\xa3\t,\x1c\x06ki\xdb\xdb\x9a6\xbd\xb3W\xfdQ\xeai1\xe2z\xe1Td\xd0\xa0\xc7N\xe4W\x8f\xa0\x8fz`6\x12<\xe9\xdd\xe6:\xfci\xae\x0e\xc3\xfeQ\xaa\xefFw{\x84Ly]\xfc\xe0\xf3G\xa8\xfeA\x9d\xb5+s\xc1\xdf\x98\xb7\xdb.tp+\xd1\xbe\xe1\x15\xba\xa3\xfb\xee\xcf\xf4\x1d\xec\x853Y\xc2\xec\x1cf\x1a5%\xb2!o\x88\x83\x14\x1d"2\xaa\xdc\x03\x97\xd2\xc7\xba\xe8\xe9\x81\xb9\xd0%\xdf\x98b\xf0' ``

What is the issue here, and how can I fix it?

Comment: how do you send it ? How do you receive it? How do you ubencrypt it? Maybe problem is not how to add string to bytes but rathern how to send data which has few bytes more. Maybe server is configured to get always the same number of bytes - so it cutoff your message.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer doesn't show the \x code for ASCII letters and numbers. the \x is shown for bytes that could not be decoded in either ASCII or UTF-8. When you do `message.encode()`, the "hello" string turns into "hello" bytes. The computer is registering it as \x something but decodes it before showing it to you.

As for why it isn't showing up, I'm guessing it has something to do with the way you are encrypting it. The digest variable has a length of 256 bytes. Depending on what encryption method you use or whether or not you padded the data correctly, the excess data that didn't fit into the block (in this case the bytes "hello") were lost.